# $.getJSON returning cached data in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, getjson

I'm playing around with ASP.net MVC and JQuery at the moment. I've come across behavour which doesn't seem to make sense.

I'm calling JQuery's `$.getJSON` function to populate some div's. The event is triggered on the `$(document).ready` event. This works perfectly.

There is a small `AJAX.BeginForm` which adds another value to be used when populating the divs.  It calls the remote function correctly and upon success calls the original javascript function to repopulate the divs.

Here is the weird part: In FireFox and Chrome - Everything works.  BUT In IE8 (Beta) this second call to the populate Div script (which calls the $.getJSON function) gets cached data and does not ask the server!

Hope this question makes sense: In a nut shell - Why is `$.getJSON` getting cached data?  And why is it only effecting IE8?

Comment: Strangely, I see this bug not only in IE, but in Firefox as well. Disabling ajax caching in jquery helped me.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just to let you know, Firefox and Chrome consider all Ajax request as non-cachable. IE (all versions) treat Ajax call just as other web request. That's why you see this behavior.
How to force IE to download data at each request:

- As you said, use 'cache' or 'nocache' option in JQuery
- Add a random parameter to the request (ugly, but works :))
- On server side, set cachability (for example using an attribute, see below)

Code:

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution appeals to me.  I really like the elegance of applying an attibute in MVC

Comment: There is an OutputCacheAttribute OOTB nowadays.

Comment: @bzlm but this is easier to search for

Comment: check out http://formatinternet.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/ie-cache-for-ajax-requests/ for a client side solution

Comment: IE is trying to be different from any other browser, again :-(

Comment: Actually, it is the other way around, but I agree as a developer IE requires patience :)

Comment: " Firefox and Chrome consider all Ajax request as non-cachable. IE (all versions) treat Ajax call just as other web request" - citation needed (please :) )

Comment: @MorganTiley - seconded. I don't think that's true. At least not in 2012 it's not.

Answer (score 107):

This is how it worked for me...

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$.getJSON("/MyQueryUrl",function(data,item) {
     // do stuff with callback data
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
   });
```

Comment: I was struggling with this problem and your solution gave a quick way to solve it. :)

I have a question, do you know what options can be used for $.ajaxSetup? jQuery documentation does not provide details unfortunately...

Comment: The available options are identical to $.ajax See http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options for more information

Comment: A little warning for the code above - it contains race condition. Because the call and its response are asynchronous, you should call `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });` right after the  `getJSON()` and not in the callback.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks Kent for your answer.
Using $.ajax('{ cache: no }'); worked perfectly.
[edit]

Or at least I thought i did.  Seems that the jquery $.getJSON isn't reading any changes made to the $.ajax object.

The solution that ended up working was to add a new parameter manually

```
var noCache = Date();
$.getJSON("/somepage/someaction", { "noCache": noCache }, Callback);
```

the date resolution is only to the minute; which effectively means this solution still caches for upto one minute.  This is acceptable for my purposes.

Comment: var noCache = new Date().getTime(); //will give you to the ms

Comment: thanks Scunliffe!  - i'm pretty new to javascript, ASP MVC has opened new horizons for me

Comment: You can also try something like Math.Random().

Comment: @Falkayn - tough `Math.Random()` could be used, its results will be unknown and you might get the same number twice in a row (or more).
using `new Date().getTime()` will make sure that it is never repeated. (unless you are able to go back in time ;) )

Answer (score 11):

I solved this same problem by placing the following attribute on the Action in the Controller:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

Comment: Wonderful! Great to have alternatives (I chose this one). Thanks to all contributors!

Comment: Works fine with Asp.Net MVC 4.0

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ASP.net MVC, consider adding an extension method to easily implement no caching like so:

```
    public static void NoCache(this HttpResponse Response)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);

        Response.Expires = -1;
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.MinValue;
        Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    }
```

Comment: Nice idea - so you call this extension method on the server during the callback right?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to send a cache-breaker.

I would recommend using $.ajax( { cache: no })  just in case ( adds a random suffix to the get request)

( I tend to use $.ajax everywhere these days, more tuneable )

Comment: Thanks for your answer!... i haven't tried it out yet.  Will provide feed back shortly

Answer (score 2):

Ready for THE answer ?

http://lestopher.tumblr.com/post/21742012438/if-youre-using-ie8-and-getjson

So, just add

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

at the beginning of your script and BANG it works !