# Jquery ajax call to dynamically add Database row wouldn't reflect latest changes

Tags: jquery, dbcontext

I have a MVC3 application, where I have created a page, that is used to add a new county to current Health Plans. Each health plan has a group of counties. From a drop down list you first pick a health plan, which results in all the county names affiliated to a given Health plan displayed next to it. For this I am dynamically achieving this by using .getJson() function from jquery.

Then from another drop down list you pick a new county to be added to the list. Once I click add button, the changes are saved on the database dynamically through an ajax call to the controller, but even after refreshing the page, the new county added doesn't show up in the list for that health plan.

I have researched the issue to see that the function that is dynamically called with .getJson(), to get the list of counties affiliated to a health plan is not getting called by the view. May some one please explain the scenario, why is this happening? How to ramify it?

Thanks!

Comment: We need some code... but my first guess. Maybe Http server is caching your request.

Comment: That is my guess too. Is there a way to set caching to false?

Comment: This is what it looks like right now,

$.getJSON('/Ajax/GetCountyForHealthPlan', { id: $(this).val() }, function (counties) { some functionality; }

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264216/getjson-returning-cached-data-in-ie8 ... is this problem happening in IE ?