# How to pass `Cache: false` in $.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I have a ajax call cacheing issue in IE 10. For that solution is to pass `cache: false` in ajax call. I am facing issue with that. How can I pass `Cache: false` in that?

```
$.getJSON(url , function(data){ //some code here }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set cache false for getJSON in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391563/how-to-set-cache-false-for-getjson-in-jquery)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/358083/393908

Comment: Thanks for highlighting those I have already checked but no one spefically answer how to `pass cache: false` in `$.getJSON`

Comment: @AamirShahzad:- You cannot pass cache:false in $.getJSON

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

i.e, you need to call the [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) method and pass the value false to the cache property which will causes jQuery to disable caching on ajax calls.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264216/getjson-returning-cached-data-in-ie8/358083#358083) by Jitesh you can try this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true});
$.getJSON("/MyQueryUrl",function(data,item) {
     // do stuff with callback data
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
   });
```

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true});` before $.getJSON() have worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass any configuration parameters to `$.getJSON`. As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) states, it is a shorthand function for this:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
})
```

So you could just use that code and then set `cache: false` or set it globally with [`$.ajaxSetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/).

Comment: But seriously don't use `$.ajaxSetup`: *Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is not recommended*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

OR:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "yourURL",
    //other settings
    success: function(data) {
      //do something with data
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONObject  jsobj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray  jsobjs = new JSONArray();
```

I had a similar issue. I tried all the above suggestions but problem was not resolved. Then I found that in my servlet class I was declaring above two objects at class level. I moved these declarations inside doPost() method. 
 The issue got resolved. !!!